# distribution upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 fails

Tags: 12.04

using the update manager the distribution upgrade fails with the following comment when setting the new software chanels:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/$(lsb_release/-sc)/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/dists/$(lsb_release/partner/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

all other updates from the current release 12.04 work.

Any idea why the distribution upgrde fails?

Comment: no, the list is too long

Comment: done under andreas@holtro.ch

Comment: hi sorry: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8360424/

Answer (score 0):

The IP 91.189.92.191 successfully resolves to archive.canonical.com. It looks like there is an error in the URL. If you run `lsb_release/-sc` by itself in the terminal it fails. However, if you run `lsb_release -sc` it returns the release codename of your distro, in my case `precise`.

Try running the following command manually, to reveal what line you should have instead:

```
echo "http://archive.canonical.com/dists/$(lsb_release -sc)/source/Sources"
```

Comment: Sorry, Eliah. It was suppose to be `echo` followed by the URL just to show that the embedded command would work without the / included.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you made some mistake in a command meant for editing the `sources.list`, since, at the end of it, we have:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Edit the sources to replace `$(lsb_release -sc)` with the output of:

```
lsb_release -sc
```

For 12.04, that would be `precise`, so you have to edit it (using `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`, for example) to look like:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ precise partner
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

You can use this command:

```
sudo sed '/lsb_release/ s/$(lsb_release -sc)/'$(lsb_release -sc)'/' -i.bak /etc/apt/sources.list
```